# Transpose Rows to Columns sql

Tags: sql

```
Date        Ref     Number
20/02/2013  980717  20503
20/02/2013  980717  20506
20/02/2013  980717  20580
20/02/2013  980717  20582
21/02/2013  981783  20500
21/02/2013  981783  20567
21/02/2013  981783  20571
21/02/2013  981783  20577
21/02/2013  981783  20580
22/02/2013  982182  20500
23/02/2013  982856  20580
23/02/2013  982856  20500
24/02/2013  994244  20502
24/02/2013  994244  20501
24/02/2013  994244  20507
```

Can someone please help me changing it to

```
Date        Ref     Number  Number  Number  Number  Number
20/02/2013  980717  20503   20506   20580   20582       
21/02/2013  981783  20500   20567   20571   20577   20580   
22/02/2013  982182  20500                   
23/02/2013  982856  20580   20500               
24/02/2013  994244  20502   20501   20507
```

No. of columns for 'number' field should be dynamic depending on the rows found for unique 'ref'

and I also need the ability to set date as criteria

Comment: Please use the code sample editor to format questions properly. What is the DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using MYSQL.

If so, I think you should try `GROUP_CONCAT`.
It will display for one date all the numbers found. And with distinct you have deduplicated numbers found.

```
SELECT Date, Ref, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT NUMBER SEPARATOR ";") as Numbers
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY Date, Ref
```

It won't display the different numbers in different columns **"Number"**.
But then you can explode your **"Numbers"** column on the **";"** separator.

NOTE:

You may have to convert your numbers to char to have them displayed correctly in phpmyadmin if you use it. Otherwise, it may only display "BLOB" in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Tostao - thanks for ur suggestion. Well I am using MS Sql. I have tried the same thing with PIVOT but i need this to be displayed in columns